# How to install the yii framework with xampp server

Tags: php, yii2

Im having a problem in installing the Yii framework. Nothing happens. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please go through Documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

Comment: i already followed the command, but there is not result

Comment: you need to run `php init` instead `init`

Comment: i already run php init. but still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem back , I had followed these steps,

Firstly turn off  every service of your xampp and also xampp.

Step 1: Download the Yii framework from from here [enter link description here](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/).
Step 2: If you download it then extract the compressed files into the XAMPP htdocs folder. at path `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Step 3: Run the framework and go here `localhost:8080/test_yii/requirements/`.

Step 4: The next step is to set up the environment variables.
From the Start menu right-click on Computer then select `Properties > Advanced system settings> Environment Variables >Select Path > In Variable Value field enter ;C:\xampp\php`

Step 5: Open the Command Prompt, navigate to

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\testappyii\framework
```

Step 6: Enter the following command in order to create web application

```
yiic webapp ..\..\yiitestapp
```

11) You'll be asked with yes|no; enter yes

12) The application is created and you can access it on `http://localhost/yiitestapp`

Hope it helps

Comment: "localhost/yii/advanced/requirements" it says not found . please help me. huhu i already added the environment variables

Comment: can you please make a tutorial on the new version :(

Answer (score 0):

**Install XAMPP**

1) Download the XAMPP from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html and install it, if you haven't yet. We'll assume that the XAMPP is installed in C:\xampp folder; and make sure that MySQL and Apache services are running.

**Install Yii framework**
2) Get the Yii frameword from the site http://www.yiiframework.com

3) Extract the compressed files into XAMPP htdocs folder, e.g. C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework

4) Yii framework contains requirements checker so you could run it with http://localhost/yiiframework/requirements. You have to be sure that there isn't any Failed status for requirements.

**Environment variables setup**
The next step is to setup environment variables or else you could experience error when you use yiic command:

'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

5) Start > right click on Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings. System Properties window will be displayed

6) Click the Environment Variables... button and the Environment Variables window will be shown

7) Select Path variable and click the Edit

8) In Variable Value field enter ";C:\xampp\php" (without quotes) at the end of the line.

Note: Be sure that you included semi-colon.

**Creating application**

9) Open the Command Prompt, navigate to %yii-framework-path%\framework (in our case the full path is C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\framework)

10) Enter the following command in order to create web application

yiic webapp ....\yiitestapp

11) You'll be asked with yes|no; enter yes

12) The application is created and you can access it on http://localhost/yiitestapp

Comment: i have not seen yiic command, is it the init in the new version?

Comment: You need to run yiic webapp ....\yiitestapp from the Yii\framework folder.